# Problems with insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, parent-child, auto-increment

I made a database recipes, it consists of; recipe's name, ID number, ingredients, preperation, image etc. After that I made a php and html script so I can search in the databese (for example: dinner with preperation time less than 45 min.). No I'm working on a php script to insert new recipes. I can insert $sql1. But have problems with sql2 and sql4. The problems are with the ID auto_increment ($IDGerecht). And with the child/parent relation (sql2 and sql4). 
At the moment I get the error:

```
Could not enter data retval 2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`recepten`.`benodigdheid`, CONSTRAINT `benodigdheid_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `gerecht` (`ID`))
```

The create script:

```
    CREATE TABLE Gerecht 
(ID      INT(3)   AUTO_INCREMENT     NOT NULL,
 gerechtnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
 personen  NUMERIC(2)    NOT NULL,
 categorie  VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
 bereidingstijd  NUMERIC(3)     NOT NULL,
 bereidingswijze   TEXT   NOT NULL,
 plaatje      VARCHAR(250)      NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Benodigdheid
(IDbenodigdheid    INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT   NOT NULL,
 ID    INT(3)     NOT NULL,
 benodigdheden     VARCHAR(35)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (IDbenodigdheid, benodigdheden), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Eenheid
(eenheidnaam     VARCHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (eenheidnaam)
);

CREATE TABLE Product
(ingredientnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
 eenheidnaam     VARCHAR(12),
 PRIMARY KEY (ingredientnaam),
 FOREIGN KEY (eenheidnaam) REFERENCES Eenheid (eenheidnaam)
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(IDingredient    INT(3)  AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
 ID    INT(3)       NOT NULL,
 ingredientnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL, 
 hoeveelheid      NUMERIC(4)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (IDingredient, ingredientnaam),
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID),
 FOREIGN KEY (ingredientnaam) REFERENCES Product (ingredientnaam)
);
```

php code to insert data:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO Gerecht ( gerechtnaam, personen, categorie, bereidingstijd, bereidingswijze, plaatje)
VALUES ('$gerechtnaam','$personen','$categorie','$bereidingstijd','$bereidingswijze','$plaatje')";
$IDGerecht=mysql_insert_id();

$sql2="INSERT INTO Benodigdheid (ID, benodigdheden)
VALUES ($IDGerecht, '$benodigdheden')";
$sql3="INSERT INTO Product (ingredientnaam, eenheidnaam)
VALUES ('$ingredientnaam1', '$eenheid1')";
$sql4="INSERT INTO Ingredient (ID, ingredientnaam, hoeveelheid)
VALUES ($IDGerecht,'$ingredientnaam1', '$hoeveelheid1')";


$retval1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql1 );
if(! $retval1 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 1: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval1 successfully\n</br>";

$retval2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2 );
if(! $retval2 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 2: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval2 successfully\n</br>";

$retval3 = mysqli_query($db, $sql3 );
if(! $retval3 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 3: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval3 successfully\n</br>";

$retval4 = mysqli_query($db, $sql4 );
if(! $retval4 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 4: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval4 successfully\n</br>";
```

Comment: `$IDGerecht=mysql_insert_id();` should be placed _after_ you did the actual insert to get the last inserted id.

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Do not** use string interpolation to accomplish this.